# Query to get the list of all user story I had once work on in Rally

Tags: rally, code-rally

I am a developer. I have come across a scenario where I need to get the list of all user stories on which I had worked once but now its owner is some one else like QA. Now those user stories have QA person as owner so I can not write query as [Owner = 'MyName'].

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Have you investigated the Lookback API (https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual)?  You can query the history of most Rally artifacts to look for ones of which you were once the Owner.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Rally but, just thinking : since it was a story you worked on, there's a high chance you have added some comments on it, or possibly even created it yourself.
Is there a way to use this in your query?

For eg - [CommentBy = Adarsh Kumar], or [CreatedBy = Adarsh Kumar]

I use Rational Team Concert, and this may be a problem there too. If one modifies the design where you have a Dev owner, and a FVT owner, and give the ability to query on these two separate fields, it would be easier to track efforts at the end of the year eh? ;-)